# Great Learning Resources for Developers in Audio Format

Tags: computer-science

I spend a lot of time commuting. At the moment I spend this time listening to news podcasts. Recently I started listening to some educational books. I found some good books for other topics, like management and marketing, but I was wondering if there are any books for **software developers/engineers** or about **computer science** in general that **can be listened to**?

I immediately though of [Eloquent Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104) but realised that code blocks and diagrams won't carry across well.

Do you know of any books, perhaps about thought or design patterns, that can be listened to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I asked this question but I realised that I have since been listening to a couple of podcasts that specifically address this.

[Ruby Rogues](http://rubyrogues.com/) - A weekly panel discussion about all aspects of Ruby covering design, gems, libraries and more meta subjects such as gender issues an contracting tips.

[Javascript Jabber](http://javascriptjabber.com/) - Identical to Ruby Rogues but for Javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you cannot show any math, code or diagrams, so it isn't prefered medium. However i listen a lot too. You can get some lectures from universities and presentations from infoQ in audio.
For podcasts, check my collection in OPML format:
http://gscerbak2.blog.matfyz.sk/Podcasts.opml
There are more of them, but I didn't find them useful. Some of the entries are more news related, so you have to listen what suits you.